# What is the difference between tension overload and metabolic overload?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between tension overload and metabolic overload? When should I opt for one or the other? It's Jeff Cavalier again. He [says](https://youtu.be/NtaPROZOcmM) in one video, if you want tension overload, do this, if you want metabolic overload, do that. But I don't know what do the terms mean, let alone which one I need

Comment: If you're new to training you can probably ignore that, and just follow A training program.

Comment: @Luciano Yup. While some programs are obviously better than others, new lifters are typically so anabolically sensitive that doing literally anything will yield *some* results.

Comment: I don't think I'm new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way he's using it,

Tension overload - Stressing the muscle with intensity which forces the muscle to work harder to move against the resistance.

Metabolic overload - Stressing the muscle with Time-Under-Tension which forces the muscle to work longer to continue moving against the resistance.

You increase tension by increasing the resistance. For example, if you use a 35 lb. resistance band to do an overhead press, you can increase the tension by using a 45 lb. resistance band.  This will put more focus on strength.

You increase the metabolic demands of a lift by increasing the time it takes to perform it as well as working to failure. For an example with an overhead press, you can slow down the concentric and eccentric portion of the lift, pause at the top, increase reps, etc. The point is to increase the time under tension of the total set. This will put more focus on increasing muscular endurance.

Most people don't really need to worry about such things. Increasing tension will also increase the metabolic demands and vice versa. It just won't be to the extent of a more focused approach which is why there is a distinction.

For strength and size goals, focus on simple movements that increase tension, and perform the movement to or near failure. If you can rep out 6-8 reps, then in the following week increase the resistance and do it again.

Comment: So if one is more interested in martial applications, they should do a lot of reps with relatively low resistance, right? But if sheer strength is the priority, then a low-rep high-resistance approach is appropriate. Did I understand you correctly?